# django-moderation with custom model managers

Tags: django, django-models, django-mptt

I am using Django 3.2 and [django-moderation](https://django-moderation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).

I want to moderate Foo:

```
class MyCustomManager1(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(is_published=True)


class MyCustomManager2(MyCustomManager1):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(/* some criteria */)


class Foo(models.Model):
    # some fields
    objects = models.Manager()

    published = MyCustomManager1()
    live = MyCustomManager2()


moderation.register(Foo)
```

When I run `python manage.py makemigrations`, I get the error:

> AttributeError: type object 'Foo' has no attribute 'unmoderated_published'

I tried to hack around this by adding the fields and creating Managers for moderated objects - but although that got rid of the errors, the object was no longer moderated.

The only way I could get created objects to be moderated, was to remove all the model managers - with the exception of the default `objects` manager.

How do I get django-moderation to work with models with custom model managers?

I get the same error when I attempt to derive Foo from [MPTT](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.html#setting-up-a-django-model-for-mptt) - EVEN without using custom model managers.

> AttributeError: type object 'Foo' has no attribute 'unmoderated__tree_manager'

Comment: Is this resolved?

Comment: No. I ended up writing my own moderation app instead.

Answer (score 0):

`django-moderation` doesn't play well with implicit default manager.

Specify `default_manager_name` explicitly:

```py
class Foo(models.Model):
    # some fields
    objects = models.Manager()

    published = MyCustomManager1()
    live = MyCustomManager2()

    class Meta:                           # Add this
        default_manager_name = 'objects'  # Add this
```

---

> I get the same error when I attempt to derive Foo from MPTT - EVEN without using custom model managers.

MPTT adds the custom model manager `_tree_manager`.